# Saving Page State as link

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I built a website that has a lot of state based parameters like filters, dates, general GET parameters that are saved in the URL.  This allows users to save essentially a snap shot of what they are looking to either bookmark, or share with someone else.

I recently moved from integer based IDs to GUIDS, and I'm worried I will hit the maximum link lengths.

Are there better ways to do this?  Perhaps a javascript library that will serialize my params into something shorter?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the parameters saved in the [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) or in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)?

Answer (score 0):

How about taking part of the string and using this:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqueId
Or just use a uid without string

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different options. The choice will depend on the requirements and design of your app.

1) Delegate storage of some or all persistent app data to `localStorage` so that they can be held by the client locally, without needing to send as many parameters to the server to retrieve the data.

2) Use a master GUID for each set of parameters. This can be a hash created over the original parameter data in JSON format, for example. Only send this master GUID in the URL for the `GET` request. This GUID then acts as a key which gives access to all other parameters, which you store in your database.

3)As you suggested, you can simply try to shorten your URL, while still effectively passing the same parameters, just in a more compressed format. Have a look at [protobuf.js](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js) which is a protocol buffer implementation. This will allow you to serialize the data you pass in the URL.